# How to run an ant target from Maven2?

Tags: ant, maven-2, maven-antrun-plugin

How do i run a specific target with the antrun-plugin from the command line?

`mvn antrun:run` doesn't make it run.

---

```
<project>
    ...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            ...
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>myExecution</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <ant target="myTarget" inheritRefs="true">
                                    ...
                                </ant>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <dependencies>
                    ...
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            ...
        </plugins>
        ...
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How do i run a specific target with the antrun-plugin from the command line?

To strictly answer this question, you can't, and you don't.

What you can do is either:

#### 1. provide a plugin-level `configuration`

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
       ....
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And this configuration will be used when invoking the plugin (regardless of how the plugin is invoked: from the cli, a part of the lifecycle).

#### 2. provide an execution-level `configuration` (which is what you did)

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
   <executions>
       <execution>
           <id>myExecution</id>
           <phase>deploy</phase>
           <goals>
               <goal>run</goal>
           </goals>
           <configuration>
               <tasks>
                   <ant target="myTarget" inheritRefs="true">
                       ...
                   </ant>
               </tasks>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And then invoke the phase to which the plugin is bound (`deploy` in this case).

#### 3. provide an execution-level `configuration` for the special `default-cli` execution Id

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
   <executions>
       <execution>
           <id>default-cli</id>
           <configuration>
               <tasks>
                   <ant target="myTarget" inheritRefs="true">
                       ...
                   </ant>
               </tasks>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

As of Maven 2.2.0 (see [MNG-3401](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3401)), goals invoked directly from the command line can be configured in the POM separately from other plugin invocations using a special executionId called `default-cli`. In other words, the above configuration would be only used when invoking the plugin from the command line.

But in any case, you can't invoke a specific Ant `target` inside a `configuration` element. You could maybe mess with profiles to implement something approaching but, if you really want to go this direction, my advice would be to use Ant.

#### References

- [Guide to Configuring Default Mojo Executions](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-default-execution-ids.html)

Comment: Thanks, @Pascal.  Slightly frustrating not to be able to do this, as obviously running ant directly will produce different results from running within Maven.

Answer (score 2):

You can, by being sneaky.

**In pom.xml:**

```xml
...
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <configuration>
        <target>
            <ant target="trampoline" />
        </target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
...
```

**In build.xml:**

```xml
...
<target name="trampoline">
    <echo message="Executing target '${mvnAntTarget}'"/>
    <antcall target="${mvnAntTarget}" />
</target>

<target name="testTarget">
    <echo message="Yay, I'm a test target.."/>
</target>
....
```

**And then, by running:**

```sh
$ mvn antrun:run -DmvnAntTarget=testTarget
```

**The Ant's `testTarget` will be run.**

Comment: Another workaround would be to make the pom: `<ant target="${mvnAntTarget}" />` and just remove `trampoline`.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the example at : http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Antrun+Plugin
Basically write your ant targets in a regular build.xml.
Then define a single `<target>` under configuration where you dynamically decide what is the buildFile name and targetName and do a

```
<ant andfile="${buildFile}" target="${targetName}" inheritAll="true" inheritRefs="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure that's the reason it doesn't work but the syntax you're using is deprecated. You should have something like:

```
<configuration>
  <target name="myTarget">
    <!--
      Place any Ant task here. You can add anything
      you can add between <target> and </target> in a
      build.xml.
    -->    
  </target>
<configuration>
```

More details here:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/usage.html